# PhpStorm not recognize my custom exception in comment @throws tag

Tags: phpstorm

I have a custom exception in construct but PhpStorm 2018.2 not recognize class and say:

> PHPDoc comment doesn't contain all necessary @throws tag(s)

```
use App\Domain\Common\Exception\InvalidUUIDException;
....
/**
 * @param null|string $id
 * @throws InvalidUUIDException
 */
public function __construct(string $id = null)
{
    try {

        $this->uuid = Uuid::fromString($id ?: Uuid::uuid4())->toString();

    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {

        throw new InvalidUUIDException();
    }
}
```

Comment: So ... what exceptions are missing (accordingly to PhpStorm)? What exceptions it will add if you choose "fix" kind of action? Show screenshots (so we can suggest more if possible)

Comment: Googled Uuid::fromString, found [this](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/blob/master/src/Uuid.php#L641), so if that's the one you use you may need to catch `\Ramsey\Uuid\Exception\InvalidUuidStringException`. Just random guess work though, otherwise, what LazyOne said.

Comment: Jeto's findings look correct to me -- that's the same idea that I had. At the same time `\Uuid\Exception\InvalidUuidStringException` is a child class of `\InvalidArgumentException` so it should have been covered... You just need to see what IDE thinks about it, only then it can be decided if IDE might still be right or if it's an obvious bug.

Comment: `Uuid::uuid4()` can throws \Exception. This is the reason why the IDE understands that this exception is missing. If I modify the method and change the catch line by `catch (\Exception $e)` the problem is solved, but then the methods that call it do not recognize that it throws an exception and the IDE does not warn me that I should treat it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three alternatives:

1. Annotate the missing exception:

   ```
   /**
    * @param null|string $id
    * @throws InvalidUUIDException if `$id` is not a valid UUID
    * @throws \Exception if new UUID generation failed
    */
   ```
2. Catch the missing exception:

   ```
   try {
       $this->uuid = Uuid::fromString($id ?: Uuid::uuid4())->toString();
   } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
       throw new InvalidUUIDException();
   } catch (\Exception $e) {
       // Do something interesting here
   }
   ```

   or (not appropriate here since both exceptions have different causes):

   ```
   try {
       $this->uuid = Uuid::fromString($id ?: Uuid::uuid4())->toString();
   } catch (\InvalidArgumentException | \Exception $e) {
       throw new InvalidUUIDException();
   }
   ```
3. Just ignore the inspection.

I think that pretty much covers it all ;-)